# How verify if a List of Dictionary contains a Dictionary with specific key - C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a List of Dictionaries:

```
List<Dictionary<string, int>> listDic = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>();
```

How do I verify if listDic contains a Dictionary with Key == "apple", for example?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `.Any` on the outer dictionary and `.ContainsKey` on the inner ones.  Something like this:

```
var containsApple = listDic.Any(x => x.ContainsKey("Apple"));
```

This should result in `true` if any one or more of the dictionaries in `listDic` contains the key `"Apple"`.

Essentially you start with your overall problem:

> How do I verify if listDic contains a Dictionary with Key == "apple"

And break it into two smaller, simpler, easily findable on Google problems:

1. How do I verify that a dictionary contains a given key?
2. How do I verify that any one or more elements in a collection meet a condition?

The first one involves calling `.ContainsKey` on the dictionary, the second one involves calling `.Any` on the collection.  After that, you simply combine the two.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know how to verify if a dictionary have a specific key. And in a List of Dictionary, I just found how verify if this list contains key/value pair... couldn't find anything to verify just the Key... and I have no experiences with linq... guess I did the wrong question on google :P

Answer (score 6):

If you can use `linq`, you can do this by using `.Any()`:

```
bool containsKey = listDic.Any(x => x.ContainsKey("apple"));
```

This checks the collection **one by one** until the key is found. If the key is found on the second item, `.Any()` only iterated over two items and not the whole collection.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use LINQ

```
bool result = listDic.Any(x => x.ContainsKey("Apple"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool contains = listDic.Any(x => x.ContainsKey("apple"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Dictionary<string, int>> listDic = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>();
            Dictionary<string, int> di = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            di.Add("apple", 1);
            listDic.Add(di);

            di = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            di.Add("mango", 2);

            di = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            di.Add("grapes", 3);

            Dictionary<string, int> item = listDic.Where(c => c.ContainsKey("apple")).FirstOrDefault();
            if (item != null)
            {
                string key = item.FirstOrDefault().Key;
                int value = item.FirstOrDefault().Value;
            }
```